# Why star pattern work with one code and doesn't work with another code? Logic is same

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to solve Star problem. And I always thought it's good practice not to declare empty variable in the beginning.

when I declare variables and assign some value at the beginning it doesn't work
here is the code where i=1,j=1,space=1

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=1,space=1,j=1,rows;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    for(i;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(space;space<=rows-i;space++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BUT when I only declare variables and assign value in for loop it does work

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,space,j,rows;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(space=1;space<=rows-i;space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why it's happening? I always thought it's a good practice to declare variables and assign some value to them

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. Look at the value of `space`.

Comment: Your first version does not reset `space` in each run of the outer loop. -- It is not a matter of good practice, but a necessity to have a value in a variable _before_ you read it. If you do this as initialization or by an explicit assignment, is another question.

Comment: BTW, speaking of good practice, code style is part of it. Please adopt one that uses a bit more white space and consistent indentation.

Comment: Generic hint: *Never* use `scanf()` without checking the return value. (What happens in your program if the user enters something other than a number?)

Comment: Finally, please learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You would have recognized the problem immediately.

Comment: It's generally a good practice to declare variables at the smallest possible scope, and if possible initialize them at the same time. So, for example: `for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case `space` and `j` doesn't reinit in parent for loop, while in the second example every parent loop iteration you reassign j = 1 and space = 1
So, on start of second iteration j and space will be the same as were on the finish of first iteration, so nested loops won't work